# How to simplify this equality: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{d\mid i} (\lfloor \frac{i}{d+1} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{i}{d-1} \rfloor)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

By guessing, I obtained: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{d\mid i} (\lfloor \frac{i}{d+1} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{i}{d-1} \rfloor)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\lfloor \frac{n}{i}\rfloor \lfloor \frac{n}{i+1}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n}{i(i+1)}\rfloor)$$But I did not figure out how to prove it. When $d=1$, just ignore this term $\lfloor \frac{i}{d-1} \rfloor$.

I know how to prove a similar equality, but I am not sure if the two could be generalized to a same form. The equality is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{d\mid i} (\lfloor \frac{i}{d} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{i}{d} \rfloor)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\lfloor \frac{n}{i}\rfloor \lfloor \frac{n}{i}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n}{i}\rfloor)$$

Comment: The right hand sides seem to depend on $d$. Should there be a double sum?

Comment: @TheoBendit I am sorry, that was a typo

Comment: The right hand side is not defined when d=1, which it is for each i.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around.

$\begin{array}\\
s_f(n)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{d|i} f(i, d)\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{n}{d}]} f(kd, d)
\qquad\text{reversing the order of summation}\\
\end{array}
$

If
$f(i, d)
=[\frac{i}{d}]
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
s_f(n)
&=\sum_{d=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{n}{d}]} [\frac{kd}{d}]\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{n}{d}]} k\\
&=\sum_{d=1}^n \frac12 [\frac{n}{d}]([\frac{n}{d}]+1)\\
\end{array}
$

which verifies your second equality.

I assume that this is
the way you proved it.

If
$f(i, d)
=\lfloor \frac{i}{d+1} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{i}{d-1} \rfloor
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
s_f(n)
&=\sum_{d=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{[\frac{n}{d}]}\lfloor \frac{kd}{d+1} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{kd}{d-1} \rfloor\\
\end{array}
$

and I am not sure
what you want to happen
when $d=1$.

So I will leave it at this.

Comment: Sorry about that, when d=1, just delete the that term (make it equal to 0)

Comment: I suspect this method does not work. $\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n}{d}}f_2(kd,d)=\frac{1}{2}\lfloor \frac{n}{d}\rfloor(\lfloor \frac{n}{d}\rfloor+1)$ holds for each d in the second equality, but this is not true for the first one.